# How to hook in wp_set_password WordPress function with WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, passwords, pluggable

Im trying to change `wp_set_password` pluggable function and add custom action to it:

```
function wp_set_password( $password, $user_id ) {
    // Keep original WP code
    global $wpdb;

    $hash = wp_hash_password( $password );
    $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->users,
        array(
            'user_pass'           => $hash,
            'user_activation_key' => '',
        ),
        array( 'ID' => $user_id )
    );

    wp_cache_delete( $user_id, 'users' );

    // and now add your own
    $custom_hash = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', $custom_hash);
}
```

I put this code in my custom plugin, but it doesnt run the custom action I wrote inside of it. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Maybe I put it in on the wrong location or I should call it somewhere?

How to hook in `wp_set_password()` WordPress function with WooCommerce?

---

**Edit**

This code doesn't fire at all, I tried to put the same password in users table but it doesn't care about my code and do the default action.

---

**Edit 2**

I comment the code in the plugin and changed the main `pluggable.php` file in the `wp-includes` folder, and added these 2 lines.

```
$custom_hash = $password;
update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', $custom_hash);
```

But it still doesn't work.

---

**Edit 3**

I even removed the whole function from `pluggable.php`, It still works! I have created a username and password for new users.

It should be WooCommerce registration. I use WooCommerce login system.

---

**Edit 4**

I used the WordPress registration system `/wp-login.ph`p and this code works finally.

Now I'm wondering regarding WooCommerce where and how I could achieve something like this, updating the `wp_usermeta` table with something custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should **always avoid to overwrite any core file**, as you will loose your changes when WordPress will be updated and you can make big trouble in this related sensible processes.

You could try to use the [`WC_Customer()` Class available setters methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Customer.html) like:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Customer Object from the user ID
$customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );

// Set password
$customer->set_password( $password );

// Set other metadata
$customer->set_first_name( $first_name );
$customer->set_last_name( $last_name );

// Save to database (and sync cached data)
$customer->save();
```

> You can use the Woocommerce **related hooks** from `WC_Customer_Data_Store` Class:
>
> - For **user creation** *(or registration)* located in [`WC_Customer_Data_Store` `create()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Customer_Data_Store.html#92-125)
>
>   - action hook `woocommerce_new_customer`
>   - filter hook `woocommerce_update_customer_args`
> - For **user update** located in [`WC_Customer_Data_Store` `update()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Customer_Data_Store.html#163-185)
>
>   - action hook `woocommerce_update_customer`
>   - filter hook `woocommerce_update_customer_args`

---

**Addition** - Create a customer with Woocommerce:

1) You can use [`wc_create_new_customer()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_create_new_customer.html#37-117) function that returns the user ID.

2) Or You can use an empty instance of the `WC_Customer` Object using on it any setters available methods *(and it will return at the end the User ID)*:

```
// Get an empty instance of the WC_Customer Object
$customer = new WC_Customer();

// Set username and display name
$customer->set_username( $user_name );
$customer->set_display_name( string $display_name )

// Set user email
$customer->set_email( $user_email );
$customer->set_display_name( $display_name );

// Set First name and last name
$customer->set_first_name( $first_name );
$customer->set_billing_first_name( $first_name );
$customer->set_last_name( $last_name );
$customer->set_billing_last_name( $last_name );

// Set password
$customer->set_password( $password );

// Set other metadata
$customer->set_billing_first_name( $first_name );
$customer->set_billing_last_name( $last_name );

// Save to database - returns the User ID (or a WP Error) 
$user_id = $customer->save();
```